# Empty object returned for uploaded files with connect-multiparty

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node.js-connect

Trying to get file details with `connect-multiparty` but its returning an empty object.

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    app = express();
var multiparty = require('connect-multiparty'),
    multipartyMiddleware = multiparty();
app.use( multipartyMiddleware );


app.post('/testupload1', function(req, res){
    var body = req.body;        var file = req.files;
    console.log(file)  // or console.log(body)  both empty.  
 }
```

Form :

```
<form action="testupload1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="file"> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
```

Get an empty object `{}` in the console when I upload a jpeg file. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: whats the client portion?

Comment: @akaphenom Edited the question. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this may help you.

```
var express = require('express'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
app = express();
var multiparty = require('connect-multiparty'),
multipartyMiddleware = multiparty();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


app.post('/testupload1', multipartyMiddleware, function(req, res){
var file = req.files;
console.log(file)
});


    app.get('/file', function (req, res, next) {
    res.end('<!DOCTYPE html>'
        + '<html lang="en">'
        + '<head>'
        + '<meta charset="UTF-8">'
        + '<title>Title</title>'
        + '</head>'
        + '<body>'
        + '<form action="testupload1" method="post"        enctype="multipart/form-data">'
        + '<input type="file" name="file"> <br />'
        + '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'
        + '</form>'
        + '</body>'
        + '</html>')
        });

  app.listen(3008);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks heaps! Thank you. You're amazing! So I was missing `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` ? Thanks again!